# Auto-increment ID

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I want to create auto-increment number in vb.net like : -

```
01, 02, 03, 04
```

etc.. so it is in order.

I am using VB NET 2008 connection OleDb to MS Access.

It will get this error

> Operator '+' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'integer'

if I have an empty record in table. But it's working when I have at least 1 record in table

Here is my code

```
Try
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(" SELECT MAX(sampleID) FROM 1BK ", cnnOLEDB)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read Then
        TextBox1.Text = dr.Item(0) + 1
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "20120701"
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Your query will always have a result, so `dr.Read` always returns True.  The result is DBNull when the table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the `dr.Item(0)` is null, and cannot be added with. I would first run a check to make sure that `dr.Item(0) != null` and then do the addition. If it is null, make the `TextBox1.Text = [YOURSTARTERVALUE];`